# Recently Used permissions by an App (Like App ops) in Java

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

How can I know what permissions "requested" have been used recently by an App. I noticed that "App ops" have nice features that could give you detailed information about app usage of permissions. the question is could it be done in java code , and if we could build an App that could do that, does it need super user ?

Thank you

Comment: "How can I know what permissions "requested" have been used recently by an App." -- AFAIK, you can't. That information is not disclosed to other applications.

Comment: Do you mean that it never have, or what google did after 4.3 closed this option ? because I noticed a trick that users are using Xposed framework on android 4.4.2 and up to get access to the App-op option. however I don't have an Idea if it could be accessed through code.

Comment: Xposed requires root. Prior to App Ops in 4.3, I don't know of anything in Android even collecting this information. And, given some of the App Ops-related changes seen in M, I'm not sure if they are collecting this information any more.

Comment: I see, well anyway I was thinking about something that doesn't require rooting.